# To which voice does this note belong? The one above or below? thanks

Tags: piano, notation

[image: Score]

Which voice does this note belong to? The one above or below? thanks.

Answer (score 2):

It belongs to both: a dotted quarter in the upper voice and an eighth-note in the lower one.

Comment: Supplement: this can be recognized by the two stems, one per voice.